Can you spot the missing animal?
There is an animal missing in the list below. Let's catch it quickly, it can't have gone far. It should still be within 17 blocks.

( fish-bear , hedgehog-whale )
( rhinoceros-albatross , chimpanzee-ostrich )
( ???-horse , wombat-lemur )
( crow-fish , monkey-??? )
( chameleon-hedgehog , dog-bear )
( rabbit-boar , donkey-gorilla )
( peacock-ibex , hamster-dolphin )
( duck-cat , owl-frog )
( gorilla-tiger , tiger-crow )
( swan-hawk , polarbear-antelope )
( gorilla-goose , rabbit-whale )
( flamingo-pigeon , flamingo-mouse )
( ibex-eagle , mouse-lizard )
( alligator-armadillo , lion-snake )
( rat-eagle , otter-dolphin )
( eagle-eel , crow-wolf )
( otter-lemur , jaguar-beaver )
( owl-cow , snake-frog )
( cobra-deer , frog-goat )
( rabbit-frog , kangaroo-??? )
( cow-boar , bison-jaguar )
( leopard-horse , peacock-lion )
( hamster-flamingo , jellyfish-chimpanzee )
( whale-hawk , goose-peacock )
( fox-duck , fish-hare )
( frog-rat , chameleon-horse )
( ???-mouse , hawk-deer )
( lion-ibex , leopard-goose )
( monkey-sloth , cobra-eagle )
( hedgehog-lion , vulture-orangutan )
( hamster-chameleon , panther-lynx )
( emu-camel , albatross-chimpanzee )
( sloth-lizard , wolf-lion )
( hare-deer , ???-lynx )
( swan-sheep , chihuahua-mouse )
( whale-frog , chimpanzee-alligator )
( wolf-sheep , wolf-zebra )
( armadillo-??? , dolphin-gorilla )
( orangutan-jellyfish , polarbear-monkey )
( jaguar-peacock , gorilla-leopard )
( wombat-leopard , beaver-owl )
( bluewhale-giantpanda , kangaroo-otter )
( buffalo-goose , lizard-horse )
( buffalo-hedgehog , ostrich-??? )
( tiger-peacock , vulture-albatross )
( duck-hare , beaver-cow )
( llama-eagle , goose-cheetah )
( sheep-ibex , crocodile-mouse )
( lynx-tiger , crocodile-gorilla )


Will you accept this one? cheetah!

Ehm...., nope! There's more to it than just guessing :)

@Prim3numbah, nothing to do with the VS

The solution is supported by the most powerful AI system - so, it is not a guess:) It could be that your puzzle will not be solved by systematic analysis!

The missing animal is ...

 ... an elephant:

How so?

 Each animal pair like "fish-bear" encodes a number, namely the difference between the AZ sum of the first and second animals. The AZ sum is the sum of the alphabet indices of each letter in the word: A=1, B=2, C=3, ..., Z=26. For example:

   az("fish") = 6 + 9 + 19 + 8 = 42
   az("bear") = 2 + 5 + 1 + 18 = 26

 So the first number is 16. All known differences yield numbers between 0 and 17.

 There are two numbers on each line. These are the x and y coordinates of a point on a plane. Connecting these points in order gives the outline of an elephant.

 The elephant can be recognized even without the points that have the mystery animal ??? in them. Replacing the question marks with "elephant" fills in some detail. Also note that the puzzle has the "visual" tag. The "17 blocks" hint at the size of the area to draw on and finding that all numbers are non-negative and not larger than 17 was a nice confirmation.

To illustrate:

 


Shoot! I can’t believe I missed that it was something to do with Pbbeqvangrf!

This is of course correct! I was hoping that no hints were needed, and you didn't disappoint me :) great solve!
